# Otimizar código SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

gostaria de saber se a uma maneira de eu conseguir otimizar esse código sql (mysql) que eu fiz, a pesquisa está muito lenta, demorando demais pra trazer os campos selecionados, já fiz alguns teste mas continua na mesma.

```
SELECT 
rc470.cod_item as 'Código do Produto',
r0200.descr_item as 'Descrição',
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rc470.cst_icms) as 'CSTs'

FROM rc470
INNER JOIN r0200
ON rc470.cod_item = r0200.cod_item

GROUP BY rc470.cod_item
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cst_icms) >= 2;
```

Esse código faz uma pesquisa em duas tabela, agrupando os resultados de rc470.cod_item e rc470.cst_icms, onde ele só exibirá apenas os cod_item com mais de um cts_icms diferente e o inner join pra buscar a descrição do produto na tabela r0200 que tem o mesmo cód_item com a tabela rc470.

Espero ter sido claro

Obrigado

Comment: Remove o `DISTINCT` do Group_Concat, isso afeta a performace e é desnecessário

Comment: Desconfio que a lentidão seja causada pelo `group_concat` e `distinct`, vc pode justificar o uso deles? também coloca a estrutura das tabelas, talvez seja possível escrever a consulta de outra forma.

Comment: Se você fizer só `SELECT * FROM FROM rc470
INNER JOIN r0200
ON rc470.cod_item = r0200.cod_item`, quantas linhas voltam e quanto tempo demora a consulta? Você tem uma restrição de chave estrangeira nessa coluna `cod_item`? `cod_item` é a chave primária de alguma das tabelas?

Comment: eu uso o GROUP_CONCAT (DISTINCT coluna) pra ele mostrar apenas os valores diferentes e agrupar os iguais, vou tentar exemplificar melhor com imagens amanhã que terei acesso ao banco, mas obrigado pela dica pessoal.

Answer (score -1):

Existem algumas maneiras de otimizar a consulta:

Você pode adicionar índices nas colunas usadas nas cláusulas JOIN, GROUP BY e HAVING. Isso pode ajudar a acelerar a consulta, pois permitirá que o banco de dados faça buscas mais rápidas nas tabelas envolvidas. Por exemplo:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_cod_item ON rc470 (cod_item);
CREATE INDEX idx_descr_item ON r0200 (descr_item);
```

Você pode revisar a estrutura das tabelas e ver se há alguma forma de simplificar a consulta. Por exemplo, se a tabela **rc470** possui muitas linhas com o mesmo **cod_item**, mas diferentes **cst_icms**, talvez seja mais eficiente dividir esses dados em duas tabelas: uma para os **cod_item** e outra para os **cst_icms**. Dessa forma, a consulta ficaria mais simples e o banco de dados teria menos trabalho para processá-la.

Você pode usar a função **EXPLAIN** para ver como o banco de dados está processando a consulta. Isso pode ajudar a identificar problemas de desempenho e sugerir maneiras de otimizar a consulta. Por exemplo:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
rc470.cod_item as 'Código do Produto',
r0200.descr_item as 'Descrição',
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rc470.cst_icms) as 'CSTs'

FROM rc470
INNER JOIN r0200
ON rc470.cod_item = r0200.cod_item

GROUP BY rc470.cod_item
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cst_icms) >= 2;
```

Você pode usar a função **LIMIT** para limitar o número de linhas retornadas pela consulta. Isso pode ser útil se você só precisa de uma pequena parte dos dados e não precisa de todas as linhas da tabela. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT 
rc470.cod_item as 'Código do Produto',
r0200.descr_item as 'Descrição',
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rc470.cst_icms) as 'CSTs'

FROM rc470
INNER JOIN r0200
ON rc470.cod_item = r0200.cod_item

GROUP BY rc470.cod_item
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cst_icms) >= 2
LIMIT 1000;
```

Você pode usar a função `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` para salvar os resultados da consulta.